# Задачи для python

Tags: python

Изучая питон, столкнулся с проблемой. Мне некуда использовать полученные знания и поэтому прошу вас позадавать мне хорошие задачи по питону (допросы гугла не помогли).

Comment: посмотрите в сторону [этого](http://hashcode.ru/questions/57307/) вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/classical/) можно решать задачи на многих языках программирования, в т.ч. на питоне, решения автоматически прогоняются по тестам, что гораздо удобнее, чем обычные задачники.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, ты можешь написать на Python все что угодно. Есть много фреймворков под python. Самый популярный это django для веб-приложений. Я бы начинал с него. Напиши, скажем, новостную ленту (если я верно помню фреймворк именно для этого и создавался)